# How to set up llvm-c++ api for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, llvm-c++-api

I've been working on a compiler for my own little made up language for a school project, completed the Lexer already and built up most of the ASTBuilder but now I want to start generating LLVM-IR code to actually be able to do something with it and the problem is, I can't seem to figure out how to get the LLVM-C++ API to work on Visual Studio.

I went to LLVM's website and downloaded the latest package, copied the include and lib folders and set them up in the project properties but something just isn't quite working, Visual Studio complains I have linker errors even though I linked against the lib files and made sure I copied all of them. Saw it has many files called "CMakeLists.txt", tried to look it up but I can't quite understand it.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: can you be a little more specific than "something just isn't quite working"? Any error messages?

Comment: Yeah, a bit of a bad description... What I mean is that Visual Studio won't recognize the libraries and give me linker errors. Updated this in the post as well

Comment: Can you add screenshots of the error messages and the LLVM libraries you have installed?

Comment: @AmeyaVS ugh, no screenshots of text, just copy and paste.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I too agree, but if it makes it easier. It is only a suggestion.

Comment: Never mind managed to get it to work... For some reason redownloading the rar file from their website and linking against the new one worked. Probably some files were missing for some reason